# How to back up two ZFS pools to a backup pool with regular snapshots and incremental send/recv

Tags: linux, backup, zfs, storage

I'm running ZFS on my home studio machine.

I have two pools:

`ssdtank` - holding the operating system datasets, swap zvol etc.
`hddtank` - holding user data

I have a backup USB HDD that I want to use to backup my two live pools into.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do regular snapshots on `ssdtank` and `hddtank` and incrementally `send/recv` them to the backup drive.

My `hddtank` is smaller than the backup drive, so I could keep the snapshot history in the backup for longer in case I need to recover a deleted file.

I used to do this manually, but it's got very difficult to find my way around the snapshots and the like.

Are there any tools I could use to achieve that, or should I create my own Bash script to handle this for me?

If so - is there anything I could learn from?

Comment: [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/842531/how-to-perform-incremental-continuous-backups-of-zfs-pool) has a good roundup of the existing systems that can use `zfs send` and `receive` to do backups.